# How do i make a random gif generator for my discord bot (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to have my discord bot be able to send a random gif of my choice when the user executes a command.

I have the discord bot all set up, and i have made a few attempts. They "technically" work but the bot would send it as an ordinary text, and would send the gif link as an mp4. Is there a better way to do this? I'm also interested in setting the gifs up to be a .env file, as i want to have a large collection of gifs that i dont want to be in the main code. IDRK how to do that lol, so pls if u can do include it. Do also want to pull some random gifs from tenor that associate with a keyword.

CODE:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="animegif", description="random gif")
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    gifs = ['insert mass amount of different gif links here']
    await interaction.response.send_message(str(random.choice(gifs)))
```

i use discord.py and specifically the @bot.tree.command function, but if you have any other ideas or a complete re-write please include them too. I will also provide the full code if necessary. Thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not here to write code for you, but rather help with an existing code problem. Your question contains multiple questions/requests. Please remove them. There are already [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274362/how-do-i-send-a-gif-to-a-discord-channel-using-a-python-discord-bot) on how to send Tenor GIFs as well, you might want to take a look at them first.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import random

my_links = ["https://...", "https://...", "https://..."]
gif_link = random.choice(my_links)
```

That's how you can get a random entry.

```py
import random
from discord import Client
from discord import Intents
from discord import Interaction
from discord import app_commands


gifs = [
    "https://...",
    "https://...",
    "https://...",
    "https://..."
]


class client(Client):
    async def startup(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()


bot = client(intents=Intents.all())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client=bot)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()

@tree.command(name='random-gif', description='Get a random gif')
async def slash(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(random.choice(gifs))

bot.run(token="YOUR_TOKEN")
```

I've not tested that code, but it should work like this. You need to create the tree object to add there your commands. After starting the bot, the `ony_ready` will execute `await tree.sync()` which does sync the commands tree with the discord server. Make sure, that you've added the needed intents permission in the discord developer portal for your bot.

Comment: There are a quite a lot of typos in your code.

Comment: Where? Can u tell me? So I can learn :)

Comment: `random.choise`. Spelled with a c not an s. So, it would be `random.choice`.

Comment: Yes true. English isn't my main language I was a little bit unsure and it was a while ago, that I used random. I'll fix that :D

Comment: Testing code is important and without it answer validation is impossible. That's why I downvoted.