# How can i fix transparency in image? PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

when i trying to run this code, my image breaks

[image: screen]

User avatar should be transparent

I want make like this:

[image: this]

How can i fix this?

```
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im_rgb = Image.open('cards/customcard1.png')
im_a = Image.new("RGBA", im_rgb.size, 0)
im_a.paste(im_rgb)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_a)
draw.ellipse((92, 193, 403, 504), fill=255)

memberavatar = await _ctx.author.avatar_url.read()

def rounded_avatar(member):
    with Image.open(io.BytesIO(member)) as im:
        with Image.new("RGBA", im.size) as background:
            rgb_avatar = im.convert("RGBA")
            with Image.new("L", im.size, 0) as mask:
                mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
                mask_draw.ellipse([(0, 0), im.size], fill=255)
                background.paste(rgb_avatar, (0, 0), mask=mask)
        return background

roundedAvatar = rounded_avatar(memberavatar)
roundedAvatar = roundedAvatar.resize((311, 311), Image.ANTIALIAS)
roundedAvatar.save('cards/roundedAva.png')
r = Image.open('cards/roundedAva.png').convert('RGBA')
im_a.paste(r, (92, 193))

im_a.save('C:/Users/RAINGM/desktop/hueta.png')
im_a.show()
```

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51487201/2836621

Comment: I fix this with Image.alpha_composite()

Comment: If you found a solution on your own, please self answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this with **Image.alpha_composite()**